# How to make potato wheel not stick to mold

Tags: potatoes

I used a spiralizer on a potato and wrapped it tightly around the outside of a metal ring mold. When I deep fry it, it sticks to the mold, even after using non-stick spray. I am going for something like in the photo.

[image]

Any ideas of how I can solve this?
Many thanks :)

Comment: The question in the title 'How to keep potato wheel firm' and in the body of your question 'Any ideas of how I can solve [the potato sticking to the mold]' seem to be separate questions to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your mold with non-stick baking paper between the metal and the potato.

Comment: Would that hold up to being deep fried?

Comment: @Johanna I'm not experience with deep-frying but a look online suggests that you can put baking paper/parchment paper in the fryer.

Comment: You could use a little egg white to glue the ends of the paper together too (not to the ring or potatoes).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest removing the metal frame *before* frying. Then lower the potato wheel in the fryer slowly with a basket.

If your potato wheel doesn't hold the shape on its own, put it in the freezer until it hardens then remove the ring and fry it (the potato ring, not the metal one :P)